# find longest word in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently trying to figure out how to find the longest word in as string and my research has gotten me somewhere. I found a code on SO that shows the amount of alphabets in the longest word

Example

```
function longest(str) {
  var words = str.split(' ');
  var longest = 0;

  for (var i=0;i<words.length;i++) {
    if (words[i].length > longest) {
      longest = words[i].length;
    }
  }
  return longest;
}
longest("This is Andela");

//This returns 6
```

How do i edit this code such that it returns the word instead of the amount of alphabets.That is

```
//Returns Andela instead of 6
```

Considering i am also new to javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go:

```js
function longest(str) {
  var words = str.split(' ');
  var longest = ''; // changed

  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i].length > longest.length) { // changed
      longest = words[i]; // changed
    }
  }
  return longest;
}
console.log(longest("This is Andela"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest solution is to split, sort the array by length and then pick the first element of the array.

```
function longest(str) { 

 var arr = str.split(" ");

 var sorted = arr.sort(function (a,b) {return b.length > a.length;});

return sorted[0];

}
```

If you want the length, just add .length to return sorted[0].

Comment: need to test if str is undefined or empty or does not contain space ;)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this approach:

```
function LongestWord(text) {
    return text
      .split(/\s+/g)
      .reduce(function (record, word) {
        if (word.length > record.length) {                  
          record = word;
        }
        return record;
      }, '');
}
console.log(LongestWord('In this sentence it is not obvious which is the longest word.'));
```

If you want to return the length of the longest word, just add .length to the end of the return.